# Index array which rearranges array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Gvien two arrays with identical entries but different orders, is there a way to find the index mapping which would rearrange one array such that it is equivalent to the other?

i.e.

```
x1 = np.array([[1,2],
               [3,4],
               [5,6],
               [7,8],
               [9,10]])

x2 = np.array([[3,4],
               [7,8],
               [1,2],
               [5,6],
               [9,10]])
```

The mapping from `x1` to `x2` would be `np.array([1,3,0,2,4])`, and the mapping from `x2` to `x1` would be `np.array([2,0,3,1,4])`

Note, in this example x1 is sorted, however I do not wish to make this assumption in general.

Comment: In addition to my review of possible ways to solve this problem in `numpy`, you might like to check out `numpy_indexed` module. It has a method called `indices` dedicated for solution of problems like yours.

Comment: There are also quite a lot related questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42232540/how-to-find-indices-of-a-reordered-numpy-array/42235354#42235354) if you use `npi.indexed` as a keyword in SO search.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first array's elements are sorted as in the example, an efficient option would be to view the two-column arrays as 1d arrays of tuples, and use [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to find the indices where these tuples are in `x2_view`:

```
x1_view = x1.view(dtype='i,i').ravel()
x2_view = x2.view(dtype='i,i').ravel()

np.searchsorted(x1_view, x2_view)
# array([1, 3, 0, 2, 4], dtype=int64)
```

In the case the first array is not sorted, you can pass `np.searchsorted` a `sorter`:

```
x1_sorted_view = np.argsort(x1_view)
np.searchsorted(x1_view, x2_view, sorter=x1_sorted_view)
```

For the second case, you only need [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) on `x2`:

```
np.argsort(x2_view)
# array([2, 0, 3, 1, 4], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I used a poor example because I don't want to assume either is sorted...

I could just sort both using argsort/lexsort but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Then this solution could work if you used argsort for the first array, since searchsorted requires the first array to be sorted. But there aren't many efficient alternatives to this without using broadcasting @jonnybolton16

Comment: `np.searchsorted` it's not working for me as expected. It returns array of 10 indices instead of 5

Comment: @jonnybolton16 Try using `sorter` in `searchsorted`

Comment: Should work if your using the views @mathfux

Comment: Well, it's still not working for me. It returns `array([2, 3, 6, 7, 0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9])` instead of `array([1, 3, 0, 2, 4], dtype=int64)`. Might there be some changes in current versions of `numpy`? I'm using `1.20.3`

Comment: Finally, I managed to solve my issue. For some reasons `x1` and `x2` results in arrays of `dtype = np.int64`. I'm using Linux currently and this is unexpected in comparison of  `numpy` behaviour when I was using Windows (default `dtype` was `np.int32` before). A workaround in my case would be to use `dtype='i8,i8'` in views of `x1` and `x2`. Therefore in general, it is not safe and you need to use `dtype = np.dtype([('', x1.dtype), ('', x1.dtype)])`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to manipulate index sets of `x1` and `x2` in order to arrive at the mappings you need. A use case could be summarised as follows:

```
def find_mappings(sidx1, sidx2):
    '''Input: two set of indices that sorts arrays x1 and x2
       Output: both maps x1->x2 and x2->x1'''
    x1_to_x2 = np.empty(len(x1), dtype=x1.dtype)
    x2_to_x1 = np.empty(len(x1), dtype=x1.dtype)
    x1_to_x2[sidx2] = sidx1
    x2_to_x1[sidx1] = sidx2
    return x1_to_x2, x2_to_x1
```

I will review the most common ways to pass two index sets `sidx1` and `sidx2`

**Way 1** using `np.lexsort` as sorting indices:

```
sidx1 = np.lexsort(x1.T[::-1])
sidx2 = np.lexsort(x2.T[::-1])

find_mappings(sidx1, sidx2)
>>> (array([1, 3, 0, 2, 4]), array([2, 0, 3, 1, 4]))
```

**Way 2** using `np.argsort` of reduced dimensions as sorting indices:

```
x1_dimreduce = np.ravel_multi_index(x1.T, np.max(x1, axis=0)+1)
x2_dimreduce = np.ravel_multi_index(x2.T, np.max(x2, axis=0)+1)
sidx1 = np.argsort(x1_dimreduce)
sidx2 = np.argsort(x2_dimreduce)

find_mappings(sidx1, sidx2)
>>> (array([1, 3, 0, 2, 4]), array([2, 0, 3, 1, 4]))
```

**Another variation of way 2** (reducing dimensions by hands works faster and could be optimised further in `numba`)

```
x1_dimreduce = x1[:,0] * (np.max(x1[:,1])+1) + x1[:,1]
x2_dimreduce = x2[:,0] * (np.max(x2[:,1])+1) + x2[:,1]
```

**Way 3** using `np.searchsorted` in order to find `x1_to_x2` and then find inverse mapping `x2_to_x1` automatically (credits to @yatu as well):

```
x1_view = x1.view(dtype=np.dtype([('', x1.dtype), ('', x1.dtype)])).ravel()
x2_view = x2.view(dtype=np.dtype([('', x2.dtype), ('', x2.dtype)])).ravel()

argidx = np.argsort(x1_view)
sidx = np.searchsorted(x1_view, x2_view, sorter=argidx)

sidx1 = argidx[sidx]
sidx2 = np.arange(len(sidx))

find_mappings(sidx1, sidx2)
>>> (array([1, 3, 0, 2, 4]), array([2, 0, 3, 1, 4]))
```

**Another variation of way 3** (simplification of way 3 using `sidx` and `argidx` arguments instead of `sidx1` and `sidx2`)

```
def find_mappings2(sidx, argidx):
    '''reduces some excessive commands met in `find_mapping`'''
    x1_to_x2 = argidx[sidx]
    x2_to_x1 = np.empty(len(x1), dtype=x1.dtype)
    x2_to_x1[x1_to_x2] = np.arange(len(sidx))
    return x1_to_x2, x2_to_x1

x1_view = x1.view(dtype=np.dtype([('', x1.dtype), ('', x1.dtype)])).ravel()
x2_view = x2.view(dtype=np.dtype([('', x2.dtype), ('', x2.dtype)])).ravel()

argidx = np.argsort(x1_view)
sidx = np.searchsorted(x1_view, x2_view, sorter=argidx)

np.array_equal(find_mapping(sidx1, sidx2), find_mapping2(sidx, argidx))
>>> True
```

Note that every of these ways could be minimized in case any of arrays `x1` and `x2` preserves order.

#### Use case for better understanding

```
x1_to_x2, x2_to_x1 = find_mapping(sidx1, sidx2)
>>> np.array_equal(x1[x1_to_x2], x2)
True
>>> np.array_equal(x2[x2_to_x1], x1)
True
```

#### Runtime

Variant of **Way 2** appears to be a winner. Moreover, it's open for further optimizations:

```
import benchit
%matplotlib inline
benchit.setparams(rep=5)

sizes = [3, 10, 30, 100, 300, 900, 3000, 9000, 30000, 90000, 300000, 900000]

def _generate_x1_x2(N):
    '''return two randomly ordered arrays x1 and x2 of length N'''
    arr = np.transpose(np.unravel_index(np.arange(N), (int(N**0.5)+1, int(N**0.5)+1)))
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    return arr[rng.permutation(N)], arr[rng.permutation(N)]

def _find_mappings(sidx1, sidx2):
    x1_to_x2, x2_to_x1 = np.empty(len(sidx1), dtype=sidx1.dtype), np.empty(len(sidx2), dtype=sidx2.dtype)
    x1_to_x2[sidx2] = sidx1
    x2_to_x1[sidx1] = sidx2
    return x1_to_x2, x2_to_x1

def _find_mappings2(sidx, argidx):
    x1_to_x2 = argidx[sidx]
    x2_to_x1 = np.empty(len(x1_to_x2), dtype=x1_to_x2.dtype)
    x2_to_x1[x1_to_x2] = np.arange(len(sidx))
    return x1_to_x2, x2_to_x1

def lexsort_map(x1, x2):
    sidx1 = np.lexsort(x1.T[::-1])
    sidx2 = np.lexsort(x2.T[::-1])
    return _find_mappings(sidx1, sidx2)

def argsort_map(x1, x2):
    x1_dimreduce = np.ravel_multi_index(x1.T, np.max(x1, axis=0)+1)
    x2_dimreduce = np.ravel_multi_index(x2.T, np.max(x2, axis=0)+1)
    sidx1 = np.argsort(x1_dimreduce)
    sidx2 = np.argsort(x2_dimreduce)
    return _find_mappings(sidx1, sidx2)

def argsort_map_v2(x1, x2):
    x1_dimreduce = x1[:,0] * (np.max(x1[:,1])+1) + x1[:,1]
    x2_dimreduce = x2[:,0] * (np.max(x2[:,1])+1) + x2[:,1]
    sidx1 = np.argsort(x1_dimreduce)
    sidx2 = np.argsort(x2_dimreduce)
    return _find_mappings(sidx1, sidx2)

def searchsort_map(x1, x2):
    x1_view = x1.view(dtype=np.dtype([('', x1.dtype), ('', x1.dtype)])).ravel()
    x2_view = x2.view(dtype=np.dtype([('', x2.dtype), ('', x2.dtype)])).ravel()
    argidx = np.argsort(x1_view)
    sidx = np.searchsorted(x1_view, x2_view, sorter=argidx)
    sidx1 = argidx[sidx]
    sidx2 = np.arange(len(sidx))
    return _find_mappings(sidx1, sidx2)

def searchsort_map_v2(x1, x2):
    x1_view = x1.view(dtype=np.dtype([('', x1.dtype), ('', x1.dtype)])).ravel()
    x2_view = x2.view(dtype=np.dtype([('', x2.dtype), ('', x2.dtype)])).ravel()
    argidx = np.argsort(x1_view)
    sidx = np.searchsorted(x1_view, x2_view, sorter=argidx)
    return _find_mappings2(sidx, argidx)

fns = [lexsort_map, argsort_map, argsort_map_v2, searchsort_map, searchsort_map_v2]
in_ = {s: generate_x1_x2(s) for s in sizes}
t = benchit.timings(fns, in_, multivar=True, input_name='Length of x1 and x2')
t.plot(logx=True, figsize=(12, 6), fontsize=14)
```

[image]

### Update on 02/25/2022

There is a nice module `numpy_indexed` by @[EelcoHoogendoorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613246/eelco-hoogendoorn) (`pip install numpy-indexed`) written on top of `numpy` that extends to more advanced actions of indexing, grouping and set manipulations. You might like also to check out [`numpy_indexed.indices`, Line 115](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP/blob/master/numpy_indexed/arraysetops.py) method:

```
numpy_indices as npi
x1_to_x2 = npi.indices(x1, x2)
x2_to_x1 = np.empty_like(x1_to_x2)
x2_to_x1[x1_to_x2] = np.arange(len(x2_to_x1))
```

Comment: I think you've misundersood the question; I want to return `np.array([1,3,0,2,4])` rather than use it to begin with

Comment: @jonnybolton16 Yes, I see. I need to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Using array comprehension this is what I do:

```
x1_in_x2 = [x2.index(e) for e in x1]
```

I do not know if this is what you expect. Please confirm If I understood you correctly.

Comment: This works but only for lists; I guess I could use the `tolist()` method on the two arrays, and then turn the answer back into an array. But I'll wait to see if there is a numpy solution before accepting this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know much about numpy, but here's one janky way to do it with just Python lists:

```py
x1 = [[1, 2],
      [3, 4],
      [5, 6],
      [7, 8],
      [9, 10]]

x2 = [[3, 4],
      [7, 8],
      [1, 2],
      [5, 6],
      [9, 10]]

map_1_to_2 = []
map_2_to_1 = []

for element_1, element_2 in zip(x1, x2):
    map_1_to_2.append(x2.index(element_1))
    map_2_to_1.append(x1.index(element_2))

print(map_1_to_2)
print(map_2_to_1)
```

Comment: Indeed this works (for lists); but @RubyLearning answer does it much more succinctly. Thanks though :)